# Удаление из Git-репозитория файла или папки

Tags: git, github, git-репозиторий

Каким образом можно удалить файл/папку из опубликованного репозитория, в частности из `github`?

Все статьи на эту тему мне попались с удалением из локального репозитория, и ни одной, как удалить из опубликованного...

Comment: Удаляем, создаём коммит, пушим.

Comment: Если надо удалить из истории, то https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Удалить локально
2. Выполнить `git push --force`

Comment: вот только зачем рекомендовать force?

Comment: @KoVadim, а вы знаете другой способ изменения опубликованной истории?

Comment: если нам просто нужно удалить файл (а не почистить всю историю от него), то force не нужен.

Comment: @KoVadim, мне даже в голову не пришло, что вопрос может быть в этом. Спасибо за уточнение